# KRACK unpatched routers are not safe to use in wireless-client and WISP modes?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security, wpa2-psk, vulnerabilities

> How the KRACK attack destroys nearly all Wi-Fi security
>
> [arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/10/how-the-krack-attack-destroys-nearly-all-wi-fi-security/](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/10/how-the-krack-attack-destroys-nearly-all-wi-fi-security/)
>
> Key Reinstallation Attacks
>
> [krackattacks.com](https://www.krackattacks.com/)

There is the vulnerability in wpa_supplicant in linux.

This means wireless-client and WISP modes are also vulnerable due to the unpatched KRACK?

Because this means all the "plain text" traffic that go through the targeted router can be compromised by MitM attack?

---

**Edit 1:**

I edited to explain how different is my question to
"Is it really possible for most enthusiasts to crack people's Wi-Fi networks?"

This question is more specific on a single issue. However, if some or many see a **narrower one must be "duplicate"**, they always have their rights to see and express in that way.

But I don't think that's **healthy** for the community as a whole.

Well, there may be just me after all.

---

**Edit 2:**

What if a KRACK vulnerable client can **lock** on channel? Does it make a difference to non-channel-lock client?

Comment: I am confused by what your question is exactly.  The answer to both your questions are answered by research on the particular attack.  Can you edit your question and specifically specify what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any device that hasn’t been patched for KRACK, and that is acting as a Wi-Fi client, can have the its wireless-layer encryption stripped off. Hopefully your favorite apps and websites are using encryption at higher layers, such as TLS.

But an attacker within radio range of your unpatched network could at least see the names of the websites you’re connecting to, because even TLS doesn’t hide that.

Comment: What if clients who are vulnerable to KRACK can lock on "channel"? are they still be vulnerable versus non-channel-lock clients?

Comment: @sandthorn, yes they are still vulnerable. The channel difference was only used in the "proof of concept" code created by those who discovered the flaw initially. The KRACK exploit detailed in the paper does not require a change in channel and a change in channel may not be present in future examples of how this exploit is used.

Comment: @YLearn Is "https strip off" also possible without forcing channel change?

Comment: @sandthorn, "https strip off" has nothing to do with KRACK. Is is a well established exploit used when one can perform a MitM attack. As such, yes it is possible without forcing a channel change.